# Properties of the bilinear pairing groups?

Tags: identity-based-encryption, bilinear-pairing

I stumbled across this correctness of a scheme:

$e(g^r, H(id)^x) = e(g^x, H(id))^r = e(g^x, H(id))^r$

and have a hard time following the properties of the bilinear pairing. Does anyone know the "rules" for such pairings or where to read about them?

As far as I have learned I know that:

$e(g^{xy}, g) = e(g,g)^{xy} = e(g^x, g^y)$

but do these properties commute, and how is the correctness scheme above correct?

Comment: The second and third terms in the equality of the correctness proof you quote are identical - I suspect you might have a typo there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [pairing-based cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography), bilinear pairings are usually defined as follows:

Let $G_1, G_2, G$ be finite cyclic groups of the same order. A bilinear pairing is then a map $e : G_1 \times G_2 \rightarrow G$ which is bilinear, that is:
$$
e(p^a, q^b) = e(p, q)^{ab}
$$

It is often also implied or required that:

- $e$ is not the trivial pairing which maps all inputs to the neutral element of $G$
- We have a way to compute $e$ 'efficiently'
- if $g_1$ is a generator of $G_1$, and $g_2$ of $G_2$, then $e(g_1, g_2)$ is a generator of $G$
- In some contexts $G_1 = G_2$ is used, that is $e$ will be of the form $e : G_1 \times G_1 \Rightarrow G$.

Thus, informally, a bilinear pairing allows to "pull out" the exponents (assuming multiplicative notation) of its inputs.

The correctness proof you quote is straight-forward, then:
$$
\begin{align}
e(g^r,H(id)^x) & = e(g, H(id))^{rx} & \text{ bilinearity} \\
& = e(g, H(id))^{xr} & \text{ commutativity} \\
& = e(g^x, H(id)^r) & \text{ bilinearity}
\end{align}
$$

You can find a decent (I find) introduction into pairing-based cryptography in [these lecture slides by John Bethencourt](https://people.csail.mit.edu/alinush/6.857-spring-2015/papers/bilinear-maps.pdf).

Comment: Saying $G_1 = G_2$ might be confusing to some people starting out. In most implementations, they are treated as different groups.

Comment: @AmanGrewal Ah that's interesting. Most my exposure has been via a few papers in the threshold setting from a few years ago, which had usually used $G_1 = G_2$. I have slightly reworded the above, to be less absolute about this.

Comment: From my experience, you use pairings where $G_1, G_2 \subset G$. The pairing might be well-defined on all of $G \times G$, but libraries only implement the useful parts (for speed or ease of hashing into the curve).

Comment: Thank you @Morrolan !!